# Rust - Vector with size defined at runtime

Tags: vector, rust

How do you create an array, in rust, whose size is defined at run time?

Basically, how do you convert in rust the following code:

```
void f(int n){ return std::vector<int>(n); }
```

?

This is not possible in rust:

```
let n = 15;
let board: [int, ..n];
```

Note: I saw that it was impossible to do this in a simple manner, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745907/rust-creating-a-vector-with-non-constant-length), but I refuse to accept that such a simple thing is impossible :p

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rust: Creating a vector with non-constant length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745907/rust-creating-a-vector-with-non-constant-length)

Comment: Slightly newer answers apply if you [want to create a vector of zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530011/creating-a-vector-of-zeros-for-a-specific-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never-mind, I found it the way:

```
let n = 15;      // number of items
let val = 17;    // value to replicate
let v = std::vec::from_elem(val, n);
```

Comment: Beware that this creates a vector of length `val` with values `n`.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way in modern Rust is [`vec![value; size]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html).

Values are cloned, which is quite a relief compared to other languages that casually hand back a vector of references to the same object. E.g. `vec![vec![]; 2]` creates a vector where both elements are independent vectors, 3 vectors in total. Python's `[[]] * 2` creates a vector of length 2 where both elements are (references to) the same nested vector.