# Creating a vector of zeros for a specific size

Tags: rust

I'd like to initialize a vector of zeros with a specific size that is determined at runtime.

In C, it would be like:

```c
int main(void)
{
    uint size = get_uchar();
    int A[size][size];
    memset(A, 0, size*size*sizeof(int));
}
```

Here's the helper function that I tried writing in Rust, but I think the slicing syntax `0..size` is offending the compiler. Besides, it looks more verbose than the C version. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

```rust
fn zeros(size: u32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut zero_vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(size);
    for i in 0..size {
        zero_vec.push(0);
    }
    return zero_vec;
}
```

I swear that the old docs used to explain a `from_elem()` method [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) and none of the permutations of the `[0 ; size]` [notation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15587) seem to work

I'd like to stick this into a substring search algorithm ultimately:

```rust
pub fn kmp(text: &str, pattern: &str) -> i64 {
    let mut shifts = zeros(pattern.len()+1);
}
```

Answer (score 219, accepted):

To initialize a vector of zeros (or any other constant value) of a given length, you can use the `vec!` macro:

```
let len = 10;
let zero_vec = vec![0; len];
```

That said, your function worked for me after just a couple syntax fixes:

```
fn zeros(size: u32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut zero_vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(size as usize);
    for i in 0..size {
        zero_vec.push(0);
    }
    return zero_vec;
}
```

`uint` no longer exists in Rust 1.0, `size` needed to be cast as `usize`, and the types for the vectors needed to match (changed `let mut zero_vec: Vec<i64>` to `let mut zero_vec: Vec<i32>`.

Comment: I updated Rust to 1.0 and `let mut shifts = vec![0; pattern.len()];` works directly now... Oops. Before this I had an `error: expected `:`, found `.`
../search.rs:17         zero_vec.push(0);` which made no sense.

Comment: I've been there myself. When I was very first starting out it was very hard to know whether I was using syntax incorrectly, or the syntax had just changed since the last time I updated or since the doc I was reading was updated. I'm really glad we have the beta now and way excited for 1.0. Btw are you using `rustup.sh` to update Rust? If so you might want to get the latest version of the script, which will grab the beta now instead of nightlies.

Comment: But that's why I like most about the language - the community support is wonderful, no downvotes for my noob question. :) Yep I curl'ed the latest `rustup.sh`. Thanks so much! Now I just have to figure out index access to string elements...

Comment: Of course, you may ask yourself why you would have to lookup answers for so basic a question in the first place. This is more intuitive in most other languages, e.g. those that default to zero when an array / vector is initialized.

Comment: A very noob question but when I did this I ended up with a 2 element vector of 0 and 3 in which the size I was trying to initialize it to was 3.  Is there some criteria that would cause  the initialization to behavior differently?

Comment: @Tedford - I'm guessing you did `vec![0, 3]` instead of `vec![0; 3]`

Answer (score 22):

You can also use the `iter::repeat` function, which I suppose is "more idiomatic" (and just looks nicer to me):

```
use std::iter;

fn zeros(size: usize) -> Vec<i32> {
    iter::repeat(0).take(size).collect()
}
```

Comment: Is that considered more idiomatic than using vec! directly? Would that run faster?

Comment: @anders No idea; I agree that the `vec!` version looks nice as well. I suppose it couldn't hurt to try some benchmarks, which I might do when I get home.

Comment: Yeah you've got me wondering now what the implementation of vec! is. I'll see if I can find some time to dig into this a little.

Comment: Using the vec macro is considered more idiomatic, it was added specifically because people did not want to do this.

Comment: Note: `::<Vec<i32>>` is superfluous, type inference can figure it out automatically since it *has* to be the type of the expression, so you can just use `.collect()` here.

Answer (score 20):

Here is another way, much shorter. It works with Rust 1.0:

```
fn zeros(size: u32) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec![0; size as usize]
}

fn main() {
    let vec = zeros(10);
    for i in vec.iter() {
        println!("{}", i)
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the last part of @anders answer?

Answer (score 9):

You may use [resize](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize)

```
let mut v = Vec::new();
let l = 42;
v.resize(l, 0u32);
```

Comment: `vec!` is more efficient when allocating with 0 because it uses `RawVec::with_capacity_zeroed()`, while `.resize()` calls `.extend_with()` which uses a more complex value generator. For other values both use `.extend_with()` so the benefit is roughly the same.