# Problem with `vec![0,1024]` macro. Why `1024` neeeds to be `u8`?

Tags: rust

My struct `UdpSocketBuffer` has the following `new` method:

```
pub fn new<MS, PS>(metadata_storage: MS, payload_storage: PS) -> PacketBuffer<'a, 'b, H>
        where MS: Into<ManagedSlice<'a, PacketMetadata<H>>>,
              PS: Into<ManagedSlice<'b, u8>>,
    {
```

I'm passing, as arguments:

```
let rx_buffer = UdpSocketBuffer::new(Vec::new(), vec![0, 1024]);
let tx_buffer = UdpSocketBuffer::new(Vec::new(), vec![0, 1024]);
```

Here's how the conversion happens:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> From<Vec<T>> for ManagedSlice<'a, T> {
    fn from(value: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        ManagedSlice::Owned(value)
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

`literal out of range for`u8`rustc(overflowing_literals)`

for the `1024` number. But I thought that the `0` is the value, and `1024` is just how many of `0`s the vector will begin with. Why is Rust interpreting `1024` as `u8`?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html, you want `vec![0; 1024]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a vector of zeros for a specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530011/creating-a-vector-of-zeros-for-a-specific-size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vec![0, 1024]` is a two-element `Vec` containing `0` and `1024`. [You need a semi-colon to initialize a large `Vec` with a single repeated value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html), e.g. `vec![0; 1024]`.

Example from linked docs:

> Create a Vec from a given element and size:

```
  let v = vec![1; 3];
  assert_eq!(v, [1, 1, 1]);
```

Comment: I don't see the point to answer a bad question that have obvious duplicate answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530011/creating-a-vector-of-zeros-for-a-specific-size

Comment: @Stargateur: New to Rust questions, didn't know of obvious duplicate. No one has flagged it as such, even now, let alone at the time I answered..

Comment: I search to find it - -, you really think nobody ever wanted to create a vector of zero ? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+vector+create+zero

Comment: @Stargateur: In this case, the answer was addressing why it didn't do what they expected, not merely how to do what they were attempting to do. There's nothing wrong with providing such an answer, though had I known of the duplicate, I would have kept it as a comment elaborating on the duplicate (I wasn't thinking of it as a question about making a vector of zeroes specifically). Annoyingly, the people who cast close votes weren't consistent, so it's not even linked to the duplicate properly now (I asked mods to fix that, if they can).